# WebRTC Audio Source for Streaming

Tags: audio, streaming, webrtc, rtp

I'm implementing a solution for listening to on-going calls inside a LAN network.
Is there a way to provide WebRTC the ip address and port as to where an RTP stream is coming? All I want to do is to get that RTP stream directly streamed to the possible listeners of the call through WebRTC.

I'm not sure if it's feasible but I think it is given how WebRTC has evolved since the past months.

I've been looking around but I've got no luck on this.

Comment: I think you need some signaling for WebRTC, for example socket.io or signalr.

Comment: @Alex: could you provide a link on how to do that?

Comment: Is this for a native client or a browser?

Comment: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webrtc/basics/#toc-signaling

Comment: @BenjaminTrent: It's an IP Phone -> web page audio streaming.

Answer (score 2):

The WebRTC RTP stream is encrypted with keys that are exchanged through DTLS. You cannot get the raw RTP stream from a WebRTC peer or even feed it a raw stream without some mediary system to handle the webrtc peerconnection, certificate exchange, and rtp encryption.

The only way to do what you want is to have a breaker or a gateway. An example of such a gateway is [the janus-gateway](https://github.com/meetecho/janus-gateway) though it is definitely not your only option.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I was reading through [janus-gateway](https://github.com/meetecho/janus-gateway) and what's in it. I couldn't imagine how to actually make it the janus-gateway get the RTP media and stream it back to the browser. The example they had was calling an extension inside that sip host and port which [sip5ml](http://sipml5.org/) also does.
Could you elaborate more on how I should approach this?
Thank you.

Comment: @Miki, if you checkout the janus_streaming plugin(https://github.com/meetecho/janus-gateway/blob/master/plugins/janus_streaming.c) that does exactly what you want, grabs an RTP stream from another source(which happens to be gstreamer but could be anything) and forwards it to the browser.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
I will check that out.
I'm really scratching my head of this requirement. So I would like to ask you a few more questions, and maybe they're dumb ones, but please bare with me.

1. How do I tell janus that the rtp media is in this port? Can I tell janus that the media is in this port without updating the the [rtp config](https://github.com/meetecho/janus-gateway/blob/master/conf/janus.plugin.streaming.cfg.sample.in) file? Or is there a way to dynamically tell janus that media is in port xxxx or port yyyy??

Comment: 2. Is there a way for janus to stream the media coming from the browser to some local port?

Thank you.

Comment: You can use the RTP_FORWARDER command in the VideoRoom plugin as a starting point on forwarding a browser stream to a specific location. I am not sure there is an API call for the streaming plugin to start grabbing a feed from a specific port(though I would not be surprised if there is). There is not a single plugin that does all you want, so you can mix and match two of them or write your own by parsing together the code provided in other plugins.

Comment: Thank you for the reply.
For the RTP_FORWARDED, what I understand is that janus will basically grab the RTP coming in from the browser and forward it to some port in your local machine right?

On another note, I was reading your [post](https://github.com/meetecho/janus-gateway/pull/255) and I was thinking that this was what I was looking for. Could the rtp_listener you created be used to get rtp from a specific host and audio port?

I'm sorry for asking too many questions. I'm really really new with this technology.

Thank you very much.

Comment: In addition, let's say I have janus annd my web servers configured at 192.168.254.yyy and I had some RTP traffic at 192.168.254.xxx:27292. Could I use that function and be able to listen to the media on some ip address and port in the network?
{
   "request" : "rtp_listen",
   "publisher_id": 1234,
   "room" : 111,
   "video_port": 0,
   "audio_port": 27292,
   "host" : "192.168.254.123"
}

Or does the RTP media have to be on the same host as janus?

Thank you.